# FAKE Start and Kill Process

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-fake

I have a fairly simple use case:

- Start a process serving an AspNetCore app with Swagger middleware for generating a swagger.json file.
- Start a process that reads said swagger.json and generates a C# REST client
- Wait until the C# Rest client has been generated and then shut down the AspNetCore app.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
try
    let createProc =
        CreateProcess.fromRawCommand "dotnet" ["run"; "--project"; "FakeProcMvc"]
        |> CreateProcess.addOnStarted 
            (fun _ ->  
                CreateProcess.fromRawCommand "dotnet" ["run"; "--project"; "FakeProcWriteFile"]
                |> Proc.run
                |> ignore
            )
    let procTask =
        createProc
        |> Proc.start

    let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
    procTask.Wait(tokenSource.Token)
    tokenSource.Cancel()
with
| Failure msg -> printfn "caught: %A" msg
```

But this is clearly not quite right. The file writing (C# client) works fine, but I can't get the AspNetCore app to stop.

The canceling part does nothing, and I don't know how to get some kind of reference to the actual process so I can use Process.kill or similar.

Comment: I don't see which part of the code is supposed to be stopping the process.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't know how to stop it. The only thing I can grasp at is the task I get back and I make a feeble attempt at canceling it, but that clearly does precisely nothing.

Comment: something like Process.killAllCreatedProcesses could help?